# anotaciones lombok para un constructor con algunos parametros

Tags: java, lombok

Tengo esta clase

```
    public class NodoModulacionTallerBase implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8795661212957302461L;

  private Integer idTaller;
  private String id;
  private String tipo;
  private String codigo;
  private String descripcion;
  private Integer orden;
  private Integer nivel;
  private String padre;
  private Integer horasDefinidas;
  private String horasDefinidasPresenciales;
  private Integer horasImpartidas;
  private String horasImpartidasPresenciales;

  /**
   * @param id
   * @param tipo
   * @param codigo
   * @param descripcion
   * @param orden
   * @param padre
   */
  public NodoModulacionTallerBase(String id, String tipo, String codigo,
      String descripcion, Integer orden, String padre) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.orden = orden;
    this.padre = padre;
  }
```

Es posible usar alguna anotacion para un constructor con solo esos parametros?

Comment: Puedes probar a anotar esos campos como `final` y usar el `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, supongo. Si no quieres usar `final`, en teoría `@NonNull` también sirve para eso (pero no lo probé nunca, siempre uso `final`)

Comment: Deberías poner eso como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

La anotación `@RequiredArgsConstructor` hace lo que necesitas.

Pon una anotación de `@NonNull` sobre los campos que quieres que sean requeridos en el constructor, o bien haz esos campos final (como comenta Benito-B) y el `@RequiredArgsConstructor` te creará el constructor con esos campos.

Aquí están los [docs de lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) con ejemplos, y aquí el snippet de código:

```
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NodoModulacionTallerBase implements Serializable {
        
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 8795661212957302461L;
        
          private Integer idTaller;
          @NonNull
          private String id;
          @NonNull
          private String tipo;
          @NonNull
          private String codigo;
          @NonNull
          private String descripcion;
          @NonNull
          private Integer orden;
          private Integer nivel;
          @NonNull
          private String padre;
          private Integer horasDefinidas;
          private String horasDefinidasPresenciales;
          private Integer horasImpartidas;
          private String horasImpartidasPresenciales;
}
```